# Dask dataframes: read_excel file by file with panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, dask

I'm processing multiple different types of files in different sizes with different columns. Files aren't too big (max 5MB and 20-30k rows) but panda was struggling with so decided to rewrite it with dask.

Improvement was significant going from days to hours. All is working fine but trying to understand dask dataframes.

FYI, dataframes are irrelevant at the moment but here's the read method

```
def dask_read_excel(filepath):
   df_temp = pd.read_excel(FILEPATH_INPUT + filepath, dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
   print("Reading file:EXCEL if headers = None - ",df_temp.size)
   return df_temp
```

and here's my simplified loop, there's more to it but again not related for this question

```
try:
    for file in FILELIST_CHECKED:
        current_time = datetime.now()
        print("TIME #4a: start reading DASK file | Total time: ",current_time - start_time," | Current Run: ",current_time - begin_time)
        begin_time = current_time

        parts = dask.delayed(dask_read_excel)(file)
        df1 = dd.from_delayed(parts)

        print("TIME #4b: PRINT df_dask partitions",df1.npartitions)
except Exception as e:
    print('Unexpected error occurred during file process: ',e)
    exit()
```

and here's what happens in terminal
[image]

Files are being read in the loop 2-3 at the time, which I assume are being pulled in parallel ???

Fast forward to the loop 9 and here's how the print statement looks like in dask_read_excel method

[image]

I assume those files are still being processed? If yes, how or why the print statement (Reading file:EXCEL if headers = None) is being executed multiple times? Is it because read is delayed?

I would really appreciate if someone would explain how dask delayed works. Any recommendation would be appreciated as well?